# How to convince borrow checker that borrowed reference is no longer used

Tags: rust

I am looking for a way, how to convince a borrow checker that following code is safe.

#### Situation

`SliceHolder` is a structure and I can not change it's interface (different library). I want to temporary set slice in the `SliceHolder`, call some method which will process data and then finish borrowing (stop borrowing of the slice). My problem is, that borrow checker don't allow me to do it. If I add to interface `foo` `where 'a: 'b` borrow checker will fail on `self.slice = slice;` because input slice can not be stored (even temporary) to the structure will longer lifetime (at least I think that this is the reason). If I change to `where 'b: 'a` borrow checker will fail on `x[0] = 5` because it thinks, that slice is borrowed longer than lifetime of the SliceHolder.

I simply want to temporary use reference of the slice and somehow release the reference when function `foo` ends so the borrow checker will not consider reference as used. For that I used `self.slice = &DEFAULT;` which should convince borrow checker that `slice` is no longer stored inside `SliceHolder`, but this is not working.

I have found solution with unsafe and raw pointers (`self.slice = unsafe {&*(slice as *const [u8])};`) but I think it is not correct way how to solve this issue in the rust.

#### the code

```rust
struct SliceHolder<'a> {
    slice: &'a [u8],
}

const DEFAULT: [u8; 0] = [];

impl<'a> SliceHolder<'a> {
    fn foo<'b>(&mut self, slice: &'b [u8]) -> Vec<u8> {
        self.slice = slice; // FIRST POSITION WHERE BORROW CHECKER COMPLAINS
        let result = do_something_with_holder(&self);
        self.slice = &DEFAULT;
        result
    }
}

// blackbox function, do some computation based on the slice
fn do_something_with_holder(holder: &SliceHolder) -> Vec<u8> {
    Vec::from(holder.slice)
}


fn main() {
    let mut holder = SliceHolder {
        slice: &DEFAULT,
    };

    let mut x: [u8; 1] = [1];
    holder.foo(&x);
    x[0] = 5;
    holder.foo(&x); // SECOND POSITION WHERE BORROW CHECKER COMPLAINS
}
```

Tried with rust 1.40.

Comment: Please post a [MRE]. In  particular we need to know what `Result` is. See the [rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust) tag for more information about Rust-specific MREs.

Comment: "How to convince borrow checker that borrowed reference is no longer used" but you use that reference. Please clarify your code.

Comment: If `do_something_with_holder` were to panic, your `holder` would be left referencing `x` after `x` was dropped but before `holder` was dropped.

Comment: @mcarton the example will fail, even when `do_something_with_holder` is not called (and `foo` has no result). From my point of view the function is a blackbox but for sake of the example you can think about it that clones the content of slice.

Comment: @Stargateur To be honest, I don't know how to formulate it better. Because slice has no compile time size, I need reference to slice (for sake of performance not a copy). And this reference is temporary used when foo is running and then forgotten to allow modification of the slice itself. And this is not working for me.

Comment: without a good [mcve], we can't answer you, the best answer to give you is just don't put a slice into a structure like that it's stupid.

Comment: @Stargateur I have updated the code so you can try to compile and you will see reports same as I. Behind `do_something_with_holder` is hidden a library code so adding it would not be useful to anybody (it does some calculation using data from slice and does not store it). What is not in the this code is that there is a loop which calls `holder.foo(&x)` but in the example is called twice.
So due to that library, I can either build SliceHolder for each new slice, or only replace the slice. For performance reasons I am trying to the latter. `foo` is my code which I can modify freely.

Comment: I didn't say you didn't, but your current [mcve] doesn't reflect your true situation, you say "foreign lib" but your foreign lib is taking your struct as argument ? don't make any sense.

Comment: @Stargateur I am trying to execute function [run](https://github.com/sru-systems/rust-argon2/blob/master/src/argon2.rs#L302) as fast as possible with slightly modified `Context` structure, so that's reason why I am trying to reuse structure instead of creating new one each iteration which would make borrow checker happy, but I would not get any improvement in the speed.

Comment: @Tomas fault is your context struct that doesn't take a `&Config`

Answer (score 5):

When trying to fix lifetime issues like this, it's helpful to diagram all the lifetimes involved. There are 2 named lifetimes, but a minimum of 5 relevant lifetimes. This is just for the function `SliceHolder::foo`.

- `'static`. This is the lifetime that `&DEFAULT` will have (due to [`'static` promotion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes)).
- `'a`. The lifetime attached to the type of `self`.
- `'b`. The lifetime of the slice.
- Anonymous lifetime 1 (I'll call it `'c`). The lifetime of the `&mut` borrow on `self`.
- Anonymous lifetime 2 (I'll call it `'d`). The lifetime corresponding to the body of the function.

Here's a diagram of their relationships (forgive the crappy ASCII art). Lifetimes higher on the diagram generally last longer, but a lifetime only outlives another lifetime if there's a sequence of arrows connecting them.

```
        'static
           ^
         /   \
       /       \
     /          \
    |            |
    V            V
   'a           'b
    |            |
    V            |
   'c            |
     \          /
       \      /
         \  /
          V
         'd
```

Adding the lifetime bound `'b: 'a` amounts to adding an arrow `'a -> 'b` on this diagram, saying that `'a` outlives `'b`, or that borrows with lifetime `'a` are valid for the whole period `'b`.

Let's take a look at how these lifetimes interact in `main`.

```
// holder: SliceHolder<'a>, where 'a: 'static
let mut holder = SliceHolder { slice: &DEFAULT };

let mut x: [u8; 1] = [1];

// Take a mutable borrow of holder (with lifetime 'c1)
// Also take a borrow of x with lifetime 'b1
holder.foo(&x);
// mutate x. This forces 'b1 to end no later than here.
x[0] = 5;
// Take another mutable borrow of holder ('c2)
// and another borrow of x ('b2)
holder.foo(&x);
```

This shows that we can't have `'b: 'a`, since that would mean that `'a` has to end no later than when `'b` ends. That would force `holder` to stop existing before `x` is mutated. But `holder` is used later than that.

---

So we've demonstrated that we can't have `'b: 'a`. What's left then? When we perform the assignment `self.slice = slice;`, we're implicitly casting from `&'b [u8]` to `&'a [u8]`. This requires that `'b: 'a`, which we've just ruled out. `self` always has to have type `SliceHolder<'a>`, so we can't just cut down its lifetime.

> Aside: If we didn't uphold that that the slice in `self` *always* has lifetime (at least) `'a`, we could panic at some point (e.g. in `do_something_with_holder`) and avoid the control path where `self.slice` gets reassigned to something with a longer lifetime. `'b` would end (invalidating `slice: &'b [u8]`), but `self` would still exist and be holding an invalid reference. These are the sorts of things you need to consider if you ever use `unsafe` code.

However, we *could* have a second variable with a shorter lifetime whose *value* (i.e. the internal slice) is the same as `self`. We'd need this second variable to have type `SliceHolder<'_>` with some lifetime that's no longer than `'a` (so that we can use `self`'s reference) *and* no longer than `'b` (so we can assign `slice` to its slice). We look on the diagram see that there is indeed a lifetime shorter than both `'a` and `'b`, namely `'d`.

Fortunately, we don't need to worry about naming this lifetime. All that matters is that it exists and the compiler will figure out the rest. So how do we get this second variable? We need to somehow move `self` into a new variable. But remember, we can't move out of mutable references, so we have to leave something valid inside.

We were already planning on switching out `self`'s reference for `&DEFAULT`, so why not just do that? The relevant command is [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) and can be used like `let second_variable = std::mem::replace(self, SliceHolder {slice: &DEFAULT})`.

There are some slightly more ergonomic ways to do this, but it would involve adding some traits for `SliceHolder`. If `SliceHolder` really only contains a reference, it can implement `Copy`, which makes everything in this situation easier. Barring that, implementing `Default` for it (with `&DEFAULT` as the default slice) would allow you to use the newly stabilized [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) instead of `std::mem::replace`. Then you wouldn't need to construct that default value inline.

There are probably some other things to consider, but without a Minimal Reproducible Example, it's hard to say what. I'll leave you with some working code [(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ba1c105dc3e7302139dd6d3565c3f1ba).

```
struct SliceHolder<'a> {
    slice: &'a [u8],
}

const DEFAULT: [u8; 0] = [];

struct Result;

fn do_something_with_holder(_: &SliceHolder) -> Result {
    Result
}

impl<'a> SliceHolder<'a> {
    fn foo<'b>(&mut self, slice: &'b [u8]) -> Result {
        // new_holder has the exact value that self would have had before
        let mut new_holder: SliceHolder<'_> =
            std::mem::replace(self, SliceHolder { slice: &DEFAULT });

        new_holder.slice = slice;
        let result = do_something_with_holder(&new_holder);
        // self.slice = &DEFAULT; // no longer needed - we've already taken care of that
        result
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut holder = SliceHolder { slice: &DEFAULT };

    let mut x: [u8; 1] = [1];
    holder.foo(&x);
    x[0] = 5;
    holder.foo(&x);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it will take me some time to read it. I have a alternative code where "SliceHolder" is copied every iteration. But my example is a minimal. SliceHolder is a bigger structure. So for performance reasons I want to prevent copying of this structure and replace only a single property which is changing between two iterations.